# Fortran: Syntax error in WRITE statement at (1)

Tags: file-io, fortran

I'm trying to write some arrays (of reals) to a file.

```
open(unit=100, file = 'file.dat', status = 'replace')                   
    do j = 1, nss
        write(unit=100, *) m(j)!, xs(j), ys(j), zs(j)
    end do
    close(unit=100)
```

However, this gives me:

> `Error: Syntax error in WRITE statement at (1)`

What an I doing wrong? Perhaps it's linked to some previous read and write statements? Because this looks legit to me.

Thanks to @lastchance. It worked replacing `write(unit=100, *)` with `write(100, *)`

Comment: How do you compile and with which compiler? What is the exact error message (all lines of it please)? make the snippet to a small example so people can test it.

Comment: I use gfortran. I tried to compile it online too, but I have the same error. The code posted here is the exact copy of the code i'm trying to compile.  Also, if instead of write I use print, I have no error.

Comment: What happens if you replace ```write(unit=100, *)``` by just ```write(100, *)``` ? (I've reproduced your error with 3 compilers, BTW, so I'm surprised, too.)

Comment: **Either** `(100,*)` or `(unit=100,fmt=*)`. Once you start giving keyword arguments you can't switch back to positional.

Comment: Good catch, @dave_thompson_085 ! Wish the error messages were better, though.

Comment: Great, it worked. Thanks

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 is correct, except for the terminology. These are not arguments (keyword or positional) but specifiers, and the rules are different for specifiers and arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WRITE statement (and one form of the READ statement) takes a *control information list* to say how the data transfer goes about, and a *data transfer output list* (*input* for READ) to say which data entities are transferred.  The control information list is the first bit, in parentheses.

A control information list is a list of *specifiers*<sup>1</sup>, like `unit=100`, `fmt='(A)'`, and `iostat=status`. For all but the unit, format and namelist specifiers the `spec=...` part is necessary.

For the unit specifier, `UNIT=` is optional if the unit is the first item of the list. For the format and namelist specifiers, the `FMT=` and `NML=` characters are optional if the specifier is the second item in the list (only one of those specifiers may be give) *and* the unit is specified without `UNIT=` (Fortran 2018 C1217, C1218):

> If *format* appears without a preceding FMT=, it shall be the second item in the *io-control-spec-list* and the first item shall be *io-unit*.

and

> If *namelist-group-name* appears without a preceding NML=, it shall be the second item in the *io-control-spec-list* and the first item shall be *io-unit*.

So, as noted, correct forms would be:

```
write(unit=100, fmt=*) ...
write(fmt=*, unit=100) ...
write(100, *) ...
write(100, fmt=*) ...
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Despite appearances, there is little connection between specifiers and a procedure's arguments. A specifier like `unit=2` is not a keyword argument and a specifier like `*` is not a positional argument.